# Crear un usuario administrador de mi pagina web y poder mostrarle solo a el ciertos menu

Tags: php, javascript, html5

estoy desarrollando mi código en php, html y js para validaciones, mi pregunta es como puedo crear una validación para mi usuario administrador y como mostrarle ciertos menu exclusivamente

Comment: La preguntas de tipo "necesito hacer esto, resuelvanlo" no son bien recibidas por la comunidad, intenta agregar algo del código que tienes y qué has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso que solicitas necesitas tener previamente:
1- **Persistir datos,** ya sea base de datos relacional o no relacional.
2-**Aplicacion backend**  que te permita acceder  esos datos y tener una entidad en la base que tenga Roles o permisos, lo puedes definir tu.
3- Una vez tengas configurada tu app backend y base de datos solo queda consumir esa informacion desde tu aplicacion web y distinguir un servicio que te devuelva el usuario loguiado y su respectiva informacion.
una vez echo esto es tan simple como

```
if(people.role === 'Administrador'){
//muestras el menu de administrador
}else{
//Muestras un menu normal..
}
```